# Reading XML file and saving in table

Tags: xml, pyspark

Please refer my repo link which have xml file in it. I want to write a code in pyspark databricks which can save the data of xml file in table.
https://github.com/sankarkumarazad123/xml/blob/main/MAT476124K0H11297.xml

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = spark.read \
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
      .option("rowTag", "name") \
      .xml("path/*.xml")
```